# To retrieve data from SQL table fields with different IDs into corresponding different variables

Tags: php, sql

The sql database table named 'data' has the fields 'date', 'project_id' and 'amount'. I am able to retrieve the total amount spent on a single project with the code below:

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(data.amount) AS wn001_amount FROM data WHERE  project_id='wn001'";

$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $wn001 = $row['wn001_amount'];
        echo $wn001;
    }
}
```

But what I want to do is to retrieve the total amount of all projects and store them in different variables like:

```
$wn001 = total amount entered on different dates for project wn001  
$wn002 = total amount entered on different dates for project wn002
$wn003 = total amount entered on different dates for project wn003 etc...
```

How can I code for that? Find arrays and loops a bit confusing. Thanks.

Comment: *Find arrays and loops a bit confusing* both of them better options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what the projects are, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN d.project_id = 'wn001' THEN d.amount END) AS wn001_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.project_id = 'wn002' THEN d.amount END) AS wn002_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.project_id = 'wn003' THEN d.amount END) AS wn003_amount       
FROM data d;
```

You could use `GROUP BY`, but then you would need to cycle through the result set to assign the appropriate values in your application code.

Comment: this is what I wanted to do. appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use array for things like that

```
$sql = "SELECT project_id, sum(data.amount) AS amount FROM data";

$result = $link->query($sql);

$res = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $projectId = $row['project_id'];
        $res[ $projectId ] = $row['amount'];  
    }
}
```

Now in $res you have:

```
[ 
    'wn001'=>...,
    'wn002'=>...,
    ...
]
```

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY`

Comment: what is  $res[ $projectId ] ?

Comment: @gmazzotti thanks, I am able to get all the keys and values by using this loop: foreach($res as $key => $key_value) {echo $key.$key_value;} but how can I assign all the amounts to different variables like e.g. $wn001=5000, $wn002=7000, $wn003=9000 etc. I need to pass on these variable values to different pages.

Comment: secondly, if I use "SELECT project_id, sum(data.amount) AS amount FROM data" then it returns a single value as amount that is the sum of all projects. Whereas using "SELECT project_id, amount FROM data" returns all project_id and their amounts but if a project_id has more than one entries on different dates then it returns the amount of the latest date. I want it to add all the amoumts of each project_id separately and return it accordingly.